# Rails Server vs creating a node server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

If you are creating a node server, do you have to have the code below to start a server with the ' node 'name of file' ex node app.js to start your server on whatever port you set below?

```
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Compared to rails since whenever you do a rails new, then rails server it will automatically run at localhost3000 and you do not have to add extra syntax like you do in node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do: node doesn't create by default an HTTP server, you have to set it up manually.

If you want to automatically create the boilerplate like `rails new` does, you can use the `express` command which will create a dummy project in the current directory (but you'll have to use the express framework then!).

You can then create a package.json file with a [start script](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html), which would allow you to use `npm start` to launch whatever command you want (in your case, you'd want `npm start` to run `node app.js`).

For instance:

```
{
"name" : "myapp",
"scripts": { "start" : "node app.js" }
}
```